# How can I change the header navigation title dynamically when switcing tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have 2 tabs and I put inside in `createStackNavigator`

I am using

*"react-navigation": "^2.0.1",*
 "react-native": "0.55.3",

```js
const Cstack = createStackNavigator({
    cstack: {
        screen: Screen1,
    }
},{
    headerMode:'none'
});


const Dstack = createStackNavigator({
    dstack: {
        screen: Screen2,
    },
},{
    headerMode:'none'
});
const mytabnavigator= createTabNavigator({
    Tab1: {
        screen: Cstack,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => {
                return (
                    <IconIonicons
                        name='ios-cash'
                        type='ionicon'
                        color="#FFFFFF"
                        size={26}
                    />
                );
            },

        })
    },
    Tab2: {
        screen: Dstack,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor}) => {

                return (
                    <IconIonicons
                        name='ios-card'
                        type='ionicon'
                        color="#FFFFFF"
                        size={26}
                    />
                );
            },

        })
    }
}, {
    tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#3f51b5',
        },
        inactiveTintColor: '#FFFFFF',
        activeTintColor: "#FFFFFF"
    },

});




const StackTab = createStackNavigator({
     stacktab: mytabnavigator,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
         title: 'Welcome'
      })
});
```

My problem is that they both share the same title **Welcome**
how can I dynamically change the title when I switch to other tab example I will switch `tabsettings` then my title would be **Settings**.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using react navigation <2 i.e ~1.5.* You can set it like this.

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Tab1:{
         screen: Tab1,
         navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
            return { title: "Tab 1 Heading", tabBarLabel:"Tab 1 "}
    },
    }
    Tab2:{
       screen: Tab2
       navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
         return { title: "Tab 2 Heading", tabBarLabel:"Tab 2 "}
    }
    }
})

const Stack = StackNavigator({
    tabs: {
      screen: Tabs
      navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
        return { title: "Stack"}
      }
    },
    otherScreen: Page
})
```

I'm not sure why did they remove this feature, when you try the same it won't work on the latest react-navigation. Now title object key is used for fallback it seems.

This may be helpful some users. If you wish you can try downgrading also.

I have the Upgraded the React Navigation to latest today for my project I think this way will be useful to someone

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
     Tab1:{
        screen: Tab1,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
           return { tabBarLabel:"Tab 1 "}
        }},
     Tab2:{
        screen: Tab2
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
           return { tabBarLabel:"Tab 2 "}
        }}
});
Tabs.navigationOptions = ({navigation})=>{
    const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index]; //This gives current route
    switch(routeName){
         case "Tab1":
           headerTitle="Tab 1";
           break;
         case "Tab1":
           headerTitle="Tab 1";
           break;
    }

 return {
   headerTitle: headerTitle
}
}
```

Comment: After hours of searching through endless issues and docs, Your simple solution helped me achieve my goal! Thank You!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I couldn't find anything but think I may have figured out a solution.

I added a navigationOptions callback for the screen -

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  HomeScreen: {
    screen: CustomHome,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      if(navigation && navigation.state && navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.title) {
        return {title: navigation.state.params.title}
      }
    }
  },
  InputScreen: {
    screen: CustomInput,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => {
      return {title: navigation.state.params.title}
    }
  }
})
```

and in my components in the constructor, I am calling this to update the header name

```
    props.navigation.setParams({title: props.navigation.state.params.input.name})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the header title manually in every single screen by making use of **navigationOptions**. Example:

```js
class TabSettingsScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    title: 'Settings'
  })

  render() {
    return (... );
  }

}
```

Comment: doesn't work, I add that in my screen2 when I tap the tabar no text is being display

Comment: Okay, could you also add the code of your tabnavigator?

Comment: I added now is that ok ?

Answer (score 0):

remove headerModer: 'none' in child navigators and give required title for screens

```
const Tstack = createStackNavigator({
    tabsettings: {
        screen: tabsettings,
        navigationOptions: {title : 'Settings'}
    },
});
```

Remove title in mainStackNavigator

```
const StackTab = createStackNavigator(
   {
     stacktab: mytabnavigator
   },
   {
     navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
   }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

use TabNavigator

```
import TabNavigator from 'react-navigation';
```

declare title for each pages separately

```
 class Screen1 extends React.Component {

      static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: 'Settings'
      })

    }
```

remove    headerMode:'none'